# Apache Flink error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Can anybody help me with the following error? I think there are some problems with versions, but I have no idea on how to fix it.
I'm trying to run Apache Flink, I use Kafka topic as an input to this
I'm getting the following error when trying to run Flink:

#### Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/Preconditions at org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern.where(Pattern.java:130) at hes.cs63.CEPMonitor.CEPMonitoring.main(CEPMonitoring.java:55) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 2 more

#### pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-cep_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: From InteliJ IDEA with there parameters:
'--topic CEP --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --group.id SBG --out file:///home/user/'

Comment: As you mentioned earlier, it might be related to conflicting dependencies. Can you run the following command `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to verify if there are any conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the flink-streaming-java_2.10 and flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10 dependencies to version 1.3.2, to the match the version of the CEP library. And be consistent about scala versions -- pick either 2.10 or 2.11 for all dependencies.

CEP is *much* improved since 1.0.2, so I wouldn't recommend downgrading CEP.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency `flink-cep_2.11` uses scala 2.11 and flink 1.3.2, while `flink-streaming-java_2.10` and `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10` use scala 2.10 and flink 1.0.2.

You can **downgrade** flink-cep to get scala 2.10 and flink 1.0.2 for all deps:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-cep_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This will give the minimal diff in your pom.xml, but you'll be using libraries from early 2016. Hence, a better solution is to **upgrade** the two other deps to version 1.3.2 and scala 2.11:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-cep_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```